# ssh authentication problem with git submodules in windows

Tags: git

I am using git Microsoft Windows.  The git is working fine in my windows desktop.  I may clone, push and pull from remote origin git repository via ssh.

When I use the git with submodule,  the .gitmodules file contain this:

```
[submodule "build"]
path = build
url = ssh://<my-git-server>/srv/repos/git/build.git
[submodule "core"]
path = core
url = ssh://<my-git-server>/srv/repos/git/core.git
```

As the git repository is shared in network, the url won't contain user name.

e.g.:

```
ssh://<user>@<my-git-server>
```

If my ssh user name match with my windows account user name, then I may perform git operation that involve ssh accessing the git server without problem.

However, some developer's windows account name doesn't exist in ssh service, and those ssh git operation asking password will fail.

Is there any option to setup in windows environment variable or other means to supply the user name for git over ssh?

Comment: Which ssh program are you using?  OpenSSH from Cygwin?  PuTTY?  Something else?

Comment: I am using msysgit for windows.  I am not not sure which ssh program used by msysgit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running OpenSSH, you have two options.

1. Tell Git to execute ssh with a specific username.  At a UNIX shell prompt (bash, sh) you can run the following before running Git:

   ```
   export GIT_SSH="ssh -l myusername"
   ```

   Alternatively, you can [set the Windows environment variable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) `GIT_SSH` to the above value.

   See the "Environment Variables" section of `git help git` for details.

   This approach has the advantage of only affecting Git, but that username will be used for every other Git repository accessed over ssh.
2. Add the following lines to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

   ```
   Host my-git-server
     User myusername
   ```

   See the `ssh_config` documentation for details.

   You'll have to determine what msysGit's ssh thinks your home directory is.  You might need to set your `HOME` environment variable to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.  Alternatively, you can configure the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to pass the `-F path_to_your_ssh_config` option to `ssh`.

   This approach has the advantage of only affecting ssh access to my-git-server, but it affects non-Git ssh logins to my-git-server as well (which you probably want).

Comment: I am running git on windows.  I think your solution applies to Linux.

Comment: It also applies to Windows if you're running OpenSSH.

Comment: I have tried both approached on Windows 7 running msysgit, it doesn't work. The only way that make it work is alter environment variable UserName.  However, this doesn't seems a good solution

Comment: I edited my answer to include some Windows-specific instructions.

Comment: Thanks.  I set a new environment variable `GIT_SSH` to Putty's `Plink.exe`.  I then setup a new Putty SSH session for Git Host with `Auto-login username` as my actual SSH user name and everything as works.